# Why do i have User registration error with MySql

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm new to MySql and i have an error this happens when I try to register a new user

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id, roles) values (25, 'USER')' at line 1
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]

RegistrationController.Java
`

```
package com.example.fitter.controller;

import com.example.fitter.domain.Role;
import com.example.fitter.domain.User;
import com.example.fitter.repos.UserRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class RegistrationController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String registration() {
        return "registration";
    }

    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String addUser(User user, Map<String, Object> model) {
        User userFromDb = userRepo.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

        if (userFromDb != null) {
            model.put("message", "User exists!");
            return "registration";
        }

        user.setActive(true);
        user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(Role.USER));
        userRepo.save(user);

        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```

`
WebSecurityConfig.Java

````
``` package com.example.fitter.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/registration").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, active from usr where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.username, ur.roles from usr u inner join user_role ur on u.id = ur.user_id where u.username=?");
    }
}
````

`User.Java`

```
package com.example.fitter.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "usr")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "userRole", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public User(){}
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

'

Comment: In `@JoinColumn(name = "user id")` you have a typo (blank space) between `user` and `id`. Check if that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one seems wrong:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "user id")
```

I suppose it is user_id in the table, so it should be:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

That was so stupid Error in User.Java instead of  `@CollectionTable(name = "userRole", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user id"))` 
`@CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))`